# guardar fechas en una tabla mysql

Tags: php, mysql

mi tabla users esta compuesta por tres campos name varchar 15, commento varchar 255 y fecha date, deseo que al enviar un comentario se guarde la fecha de la publicacion del comentario en el campo date

```
<form method="get" action="conexion.php">
<input type="text" name="name">
<textarea rows="5" cols="5" name="commento"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>



<?php
$conexion = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'admin');
mysql_select_db('test', $conexion) or die (mysql_error());

$name = $_GET['name'];

$commento = $_GET['commento'];

$fecha= date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$sql = "INSERT INTO commenti (name, commento, fecha) VALUES ('$name', '$commento', '$fecha')" ;
mysql_query($sql);

echo $name;
echo $commento;
echo $fecha;

?>
```

en consola cuando ejecuto la sentencia

```
select * from commenti 
output
empty set
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentar añadir las funciones `CURRENT_TIME()` o `now()` a la query

```
INSERT INTO commenti (name, commento, fecha) VALUES ('$name', '$commento', NOW())
```

o

```
INSERT INTO commenti (name, commento, fecha) VALUES ('$name', '$commento', CURRENT_TIME())
```

o puedes probar a generar la fecha en php e instertar la variable en la query.

```
$fecha= date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Comment: por algun extraño motivo los datos no se guardan en la tabla, me devuelve un set vacio, a que se puede deber

Comment: Las comillas de tu query name y commento no estaban bien. Prueba las opciones que te he sugerido y para saber qué más te puede estar pasando modifica al código con las cambios que hayas hecho sobre el comentario anterior.

Comment: acabo de modificarlo y todavia obtengo la tabla vacia

Comment: Las variables que sean cadenas deben estar entre comillas también

Comment: acabo de entrecomillar las variables de tipo cadena y sigue lo mismo

Comment: acabo de solucionarlo, no habia escrito bien el nombre del campo

Answer (score 1):

Para añadir la fecha del sistema

```
INSERT INTO commenti ('name', 'commento', SYSDATE()) VALUES ($name, $commento, $fecha)
```